# call back when Shiny renderUI is done

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I need to load UI and server dynamically. The server function is looking for some input values from the UI, so I need to load the UI first before loading the server functions. Is there a way to know the UI rendering, including Shiny input registering is done and then do something on server?

Think about this simple example:

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("a", "add UI"),
  uiOutput("ui_out")
)

loadserver <- function(input, output, session){
    if(input$n1000 > 0) print(1)
    #### many other things
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    flags <- reactiveValues()
    observeEvent(input$a, {
        output$ui_out <- renderUI({
            lapply(1:1000, function(i) {
                numericInput(paste0("n", i), paste0("n", i), value = 0)
            })
        })
        flags$a <- TRUE
    })
    observeEvent(flags$a, {
        req(flags$a)
        loadserver(input, output, session)
    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Imagine we have a button, on click, it will render a very very large UI which takes many seconds to load. Meanwhile, on the server, we also have a `flag` for a, when the UI is rendering, it will become `TRUE`, so in another `observer` I can load the server corresponding to the rendered UI.

Problem: The server functions are looking for some `input` values from the UI we just rendered immediately after loading. However, the UI rendering is still ongoing and the expected `input$n1000` is not rendered or registered in Shiny. The result is it will throw errors because `input$n1000` is `NULL`: `Warning: Error in if: argument is of length zero`.

I can add `req(input$n1000)` in `loadserver` to prevent this, but imagine these functions are not written by me and I have no control over what is in there. I only know if I call the function in normal way (directly load UI and server on app start instead of `renderUI`), it will work, and also if we wait until the rendering is done, it will also work. So the problem how do we know if the rendering is finished?

PS: I know I can watch for some shiny js event like `shiny:value` but it doesn't tell me the input registration or the html/js loading is complete.

### updates:

The temporary solution is provided by the Shiny team and for those of you who are curious, the link is [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/3348). I posted the link as an answer but got deleted by @Bhargav Rao for no reason. sorry but have to post the link in the question.

Comment: For the "throw errors", use `shiny::req(input$n1000)`. It's not what you asked for, but it'll prevent cascading reactivity problems from not-yet-initialized components (without showing errors). There's also `validate`/`need`, which can serve a slightly different purpose.

Comment: > "I can add req(input$n1000) in loadserver to prevent this, but imagine these functions are not written by me and I have no control over what is in there."

So imagine the server function comes from a package and you cannot use any  `req` or `validate`.